Unary operations on graphs.
I am already familiar with some basic unary operations on simple, undirected graphs. For example, complement of a graph ($G^c$), line graph ($L(G)$), power of a graph ($G^k$), neighborhood graph ($N(G)$), graph subdivision.
While some unary operations on graphs keep the vertex set same (for example, graph complement, graph power, neighborhood graph), most of the unary operations on graphs I know about alter the vertex set (for example, line graph, subdivision graph).
One may see this for some other various unary operations on graphs.
I want to know about some unary operations on simple, undirected graphs along with some references which keep the vertex set same as the mother graph.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_graph (directed graph)

I just edited my query a bit. I want some examples in simple, undirected graphs.

The Hamiltonian closure appears in the Bondy–Chvátal theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path#Bondy%E2%80%93Chv%C3%A1tal_theorem
